# How to Import Salesforce Data to Marketing Cloud using Import Activity?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I'm Trying to Import Salesforce Data to Marketing Cloud using Import Activity.
But that's cannot work with marketing cloud. 
and I've refered following document : 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_salesforce_data_extensions.htm&type=5

1. Create Report that include Contact ID, LastName, FirstName, FullName, Email based on Contact Object and save report Marketing Cloud Admin Folder.
2. Move to Interaction -> Import in Marketing Cloud and Click the Create Button.
3. Enetered Name Column and Select Salesforce Report on File location, Find previous Created Salesforce Report.
4. Select Overwrite Option on Update Type And Click Save.
5. going back to the previous page, Check Created Import Definition and run.
6. that Import Definition has Import Fail error occured.

What is I missing of those steps?

[image: Salesforce Report]

[image: Marketing Cloud Import Definition]

[image: Fail Error]

**--------Import Completion Error Email--------**
[image: Import Error Email]

Comment: Can you post your Data Extension structure? What is the primary key? Are all the other fields nullable? I see that Email and First Name are emty on your report..

Comment: @RachidMamai Thank you for your reply. I made Contact ID with a Unique Key, and all the other field checked nullable. How can i solve those problem?

Comment: Did you retry the import?

Comment: @RachidMamai Yes, I've tried import again it but still errer occured.

Comment: Add your email to the "Import Completion Settings" so that you can get an email with more details about the errors

Comment: @Rachid Mamai Actually I'm already setting up "Import Completion Setting" but they don't provide exactly what I missed.

Comment: @KimSeungJu, Are you an integrated user and have permissions to import using reports. And can you share excerpt from the error email generated? Usually, it will have an attachment to why imports failing.

Comment: It may be related to the Report itself. I have seen many imports that fail due to the "Show" option on the Report being set to "My Contacts" or "My Accounts". Try changing it to "All Contacts" and attempt the import again.

Comment: @VijayaKapadam, Sorry for the late reply. integrated user has been system administrator profile and also all about permission. but it is not working properly. I updated the question including error picture. please check again. and Could you recommand another way?

Comment: @lilDabz Sorry for the late reply, report Import is not working properly Even though I've changed "Show" Option "My Contacts" to "All Contacts". Have you another way for solve this problem?

Comment: @KimSeungJu, I feel lulDabz is  on the right  track. In addition to what was suggested try to store the report in a public folders which an integrated user has access to. Definitely something with sharing and Visibility that is causing it.

Comment: @VijayaKapadam Thank you for quick reply! I've moved the report from Marketing Cloud admin folder to Public Folder as following your additional suggestion. but, still not working. :'(

Answer (score 0):

The process that imports Salesforce reports into Marketing Cloud uses the classic core reports UI feature. If a lightning-only feature is used in a report, that report can not be used for a Salesforce import to the marketing cloud. So if a report is not viewable in Classic UI, it can not be imported into Marketing cloud DE.

The common reason why this happens is when your report includes Row-Level Formulas
or Count Unique Values.

Answer (score 0):

There could many possible reasons of Import Failure.
Firstly check the DE (Datatype and Length) you have created in SFMC into which you are trying to import your data. There could be an issue related to the data fields.
for eg: As per the image I can see your Email Column has '-' hypen for few rows. Now if your SFMC DE Email Datatype is 'EmailAddress' the import will fail because of invalid format.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/194968)